# My code is not working properly when I attempt to login

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my first time I'm using Mysqli. So may be I did some mistake. Well, I've successfully inserted all the data for registration purpose including following password hash to Mysql database.

```
//for password 
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));    
$pass = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);
```

Well, when I login with following code It's showing my custom error message **"Email address or password is not correct"**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once("includes/config.php");

    $email = inputvalid($_POST['email']);
    $password = inputvalid($_POST['password']);

    //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));
    //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
    //$pass = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);


    $salt = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT salt FROM members WHERE email = '$email'");
    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($salt, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $salt = $res['salt'];

    $password2  = hash('sha512', $password.$salt);

    $check = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email='$email' AND password = '$password2' ");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($check);

    $isActive =  mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT is_active FROM members WHERE email = '$email' ");
    $res =  mysqli_fetch_array($isActive, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $isActive = $res['is_active'];

    $msg =  array();
    $msg['error'] = false;



                    if(empty($email) && empty($password)){  
                        $msg[] = "Both field require";  
                        $msg['error'] = true;
                    }                   
                    elseif($num == 0){
                        $msg[] = "Email address or password is not correct";    
                        $msg['error'] = true;
                        echo mysql_error();
                    }elseif($isActive == 0) {
                        $msg[] = "Sorry, you account has not been activated.";  
                        $msg['error'] = true;
                    }




    if($msg['error'] === false)
    {
    //Begin form success functionality

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password2; 

            if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))
            {
                $msg[] = '<br/><font color="b9c025">Successfully login.</font><br/><br/>';          
            }
            else
            {
                $msg[] = "Session not registererd"; 
                $msg[] =  "The reasone is " . mysql_error(); 
            }

    //update database...
    $date = date("d-m-y h:m:s");        
    $update = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE members SET last_visit_dt = '$date', pageviews  = pageviews + 1  WHERE email = '$email'");
    }       

$another = "close";
echo  json_encode($msg);



?>
```

Can anyone help me with that ?

Update:

```
function inputvalid($para){
return mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($para)));
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error()` those two APIs don't mix.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did it now in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

Replacing

```
$check = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email='$email' AND password = '$password2' ");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($check);
```

By

```
$check = mysqli_real_query($mysqli, "SELECT email, password FROM members WHERE email='$email' AND password = '$password2' ");
$result = mysqli_store_result($mysqli);
$num = $result->num_rows;
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: what for he should try that?

Comment: you had different problem

Comment: Ofc, you know my problems better than me...
Giving my solution a try would cost him just a minute.

Comment: this is not a solution but just random shoot in nowhere

Comment: The solution i gived worked for me. That's it.
He is doind actions on his database while using mysqli_query but he is not storing results. That's why he is able to INSERT some datas but $num will always be 0 and he will get this error "Email address or password is not correct" as specified in his question.

Comment: please, you have no idea what are you talking about

Comment: If you say so.
Maybe you can tell us the solution ?
I'm just trying to "help" him

Comment: in fact, the only help he can get is to **learn** first. This post is not a question. this is just a wall of code and nobody knows which part the problem belongs to. And even if problem even in the code at all, but not in the data or something else

Comment: @Babu: The code I pasted you is working at 100% for me. You should look at your datas.

Comment: @Copy Now when i delete `MYSQLI_NUM` from `$res = mysqli_fetch_array($salt, MYSQLI_NUM);`then my code and your code both is working. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Copy I found another problem in my custom function called `inputvalid`. Now I'm using `return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($para)));` IT'S WORKING FINE. BUT if i use `return mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($mysqli ,$para)));` then it's not working. It's saying.. `Both field required.`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp
Problem is coming from your trim usage

Comment: @Copy I test it. But not working still saying..both filed required message.

Comment: The best to do is to post another question with a precise title and show us every part of your code refering to your error.
And what did you tested ?
If mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($para))); is working, why don't you use it ?